# Python print every 100th item in list

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a list of items and I want to print every 100th item.  `ie 99,199,299.`
My list is `list_of_numbers = range(0,1300)`

```
t
for i in range(len(list_of_ints)):
    t= t+ list_of_ints[i]
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print(i,t)
```

This is printing `0 0`
This is printing `100 0`
This is printing `200 0`

How do I print `99 total`
How do I print `199 total`
How do I print `299 total`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to adapt it based on this:

```
for i in range(0,10000):
    if i % 100 == 99:
        print(i,'total')
```

```
99 total
199 total
299 total
399 total
499 total
599 total
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through every 100th element of the list using `[99::100]` as the index:

```
list_of_numbers = range(1300)
print('\n'.join(f'{l} total' for l in list_of_numbers[99::100]))
```

Output:

```
99 total
199 total
299 total
399 total
499 total
...
```